# Selenium WebDriver Python, search WebElement

Tags: python, selenium

i am using Selenium to scrape some stuff live, but i can't seem to search a WebElement even tho the docs say i can.

```
while True:
    try:
        member = self.pdriver.find_all("sv:member_profile")[index]
        self.pdriver.info_log("Found a member")
    except IndexError:
        self.pdriver.info_log("No more members")
        break

    member.highlight(style = self.pdriver.get_config_value("highlight:style_on_assertion_success"))

    profile = {}
    profile["name"] = member.findElement("sv:member_name").get_attribute('innerHTML')
    profile["image"] = member.findElement("sv:member_image").get_attribute('src')
    profile["link"] = member.findElement("sv:member_link").get_attribute('href')

    members.append(profile)
    index += 1
```

This returns a single web element:

```
member = self.pdriver.find_all("sv:member_profile")[index]
```

which i need to search, according to the docs, this element would also have the findElement method, seems not to be the case tho?

> AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'findElement'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error states, [`WebElement`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement) object has no attribute `findElement`. Depending  on what are `sv:member_name`, `sv:member_image` and `sv:member_link`, you need to choose which of the [`find_element_by_*` methods](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element_by_class_name) you need to use.

For instance, if `sv:member_name` is a CSS selector:

```
profile["name"] = member.find_element_by_css_selector("sv:member_name").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Or, you may also use the [`find_element()`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.find_element) method directly supplying the `By` value:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

profile["name"] = member.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "sv:member_name").get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: sv:member_name uses a css selector: selector_dict['member_name'] = "cs:.fsl.fwb.fcb > a" where .fsl.fwb.fcb > a is a child of the member element

Comment: Got it working like this: profile["name"] = member.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".fsl.fwb.fcb > a").get_attribute('innerHTML') thanks a bunch