# Not able to scrape a class with different values

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I tried a lot of methods of fixing this. I finally thought i had the answer but then i got the following error: **AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'findElements'**. Currently i have this:

```
 import sys
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import pandas as pd

# accepting cookies
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# default number of scraped pages
num_page = 5

url=  "https://uk.hotels.com/ho565623/?q-check-in=2021-10-16&q-check-out=2021-10-17&q-rooms=1&q-room-0-adults=2&q-room-0-children=0&WOD=6&WOE=7&JHR=2&FPQ=3&MGT=1&ZSX=0&SYE=3&YGF=2&pos=HCOM_UK&locale=en_GB"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button[2]'))).click()

time.sleep(2)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seoReviews4"]/div/div[2]/a').click()

scrapedReviews=[]
# change the value inside the range to save more or less reviews
for i in range(0, num_page):

    # expand the review 
    time.sleep(2)

    container = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-panel-property-reviews-0"]/section/div/div[3]/ul')


    for j in range(len(container)):
        Hotel_Address = container[j].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="overview1"]/div[2]/section[1]/section/div/div/div/span/span[2]').text
        Average_Score = container[j].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="seoReviews4"]/div/div[1]/div/span[1]').text
        Hotel_Name = container[j].find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="main"]/div[2]/div/div/section[2]/div[1]/div[1]/h1').text
        rating = container[j].findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="modal-panel-property-reviews-0"]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]')).text
        review = container[j].findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="modal-panel-property-reviews-0"]/section/div/div[3]/ul/li[1]/p[1]')).text
        Oorsprong = 'Webscraper'    
        scrapedReviews.append([Hotel_Address,Average_Score, Hotel_Name,review,rating,Oorsprong]) 
        
    # change the page     
    time.sleep(5)       
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="modal-panel-property-reviews-0"]/section/div/div[3]/div/button').click()

scrapedReviewsDF = pd.DataFrame(scrapedReviews, columns=['Hotel_Address','Average_Score','Hotel_Name','review', 'rating', 'Oorsprong'])
driver.quit()
print( 'Ready scraping ....')
scrapedReviewsDF.to_csv("Reviewscraper3.csv", sep=';',index= False)
```

It's regarding the Rating and review values. The site is uk.hotels.com

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium WebDriver Python, search WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34445280/selenium-webdriver-python-search-webelement)

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: first you should check [selenium documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) - and you would find page [Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) - and you would no have to ask question

Answer (score 0):

The function you are looking for is find_elements not findElements.

Error Code:

```
container[j].findElements(By.xpath('//*[@id="modal-panel-property-reviews-0"]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]')).text
```

Correct function:

```
container[j].find_elements(By.xpath('//*[@id="modal-panel-property-reviews-0"]/section/div/div[2]/div[1]/span[1]')).text
```

Kindly change this at all locations and retry. Thank You.